# How to omit terminating pods from output with go templates

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates

On a project I’m working on at my current job, I’ve come across a problem where I needed to get container versions from all pods with `kubectl get pods -o go-template`. Then I found bug in code that is related to terminating pods - during short period of time when new deployment is done, there are two different pod version and I need to filter them out:

```
kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{ range .items }}{{"\n"}}{{ .metadata.name }}{{" - "}}{{ range .spec.containers }}{{ .image }}{{" "}}{{ end }}{{ end }}
```

I have found some information about how to omit terminating pods, but in most cases it was simple `grep -v`, which is unsuitable when using go-template output.

How can I omit pods that are terminating specifically with go-template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that Kubernetes does not support `Terminating` pod [phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) per se. It calculates it (see [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a9f6b93b62a98598913180c640ab044c85a6718b/pkg/printers/internalversion/printers.go#L695-L781)) - specifically if the field `DeletionTimestamp` is set, then the pod is usually in terminating state. Therefore this does the trick:

```
kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{ range .items }}{{if not .metadata.deletionTimestamp }}{{"\n"}}{{ .metadata.name }}{{":: "}}{{ range .spec.containers }}{{ .image }}{{" "}}{{ end }}{{ end }}{{ end }}
```